# Add labels to Gmail message while using /users.messages/send

Tags: gmail-api

While sending an email using the [`/users.messages/send`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send) API, is it possible to assign the message with a label in the same API call?

I'm aware you can use [`modify`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify) to apply a label to the message but I cannot include the `gmail.modify` scope for this application so using that endpoint isn't an option for me. The documentation says that the `send` endpoint takes an instance of [`Message`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message), which allows for a `labelIds` key.

I've tried making the API request with the JSON body below. It **successfully** sends the email but it does not assign the label. Since the email is sent, I'm confident the raw message is not the issue. I suspect this endpoint is just ignoring the `labelIds` part of the body instead.

Does anyone know if it's possible to set the label while using the `send` endpoint?

```json
{
  "raw": "<RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded string>",
  "labelIds": [
    "Label_1"
  ]
}
```

I obtained the ID, `Label_1`, from the labels endpoint directly so the ID is correct.

These are the scopes that my client + user are approved to use. That being said, I also included extra scopes to test but the same issue occurs, the labels aren't set even if you have `gmail.modify` and `gmail.compose` scopes approved.

```
userinfo.email
userinfo.profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly
```

**Edit:** In case this is a bug, I filed a [ticket with Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175241006) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is intended behaviour.

This was reported before in Issue Tracker, and the response was:

> This behaviour is working as intended, labels can only added for inserted/imported messages. For sent messages, you can use [users.messages.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/modify) to **update** the labels after the message is sent.

Nevertheless, since setting labels when sending a message is possible via UI, I'd say this could be a valid feature request. I'd suggest you to file one.

#### Reference:

- [Gmail API cannot add label IDs to messages being composed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169874640)